# Spring Boot Soap Service Performance Question

Tags: spring-boot

I am load testing a stub I created in soapUI.  My stub is very simple, it takes a request then does a **Thread.sleep(X) **(picked up from an application.properties file).  It is a Spring Boot soap service and my question is this.

If I have X as like 1 MS, my application handles thousands of TPS (Transactions Per Second),  If I change that Thread.sleep to something Like 10 seconds, it only handles like 5 TPS.  What is the limiting factor that is causing the degradation?

I have plenty of threads, CPU and Memory available.  How can I make it so It will utilize all of my resources, and have a higher TPS, but mimic a delay?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: After further Research I think it has to do with running out of http-nio-8080-exec threads.  How do I create more of these?

Comment: After even further research it seems to be part of my soap endpoint impl.  It seems that the service can only handle a certain amount of input no matter what I change  endpoint.setExecutor() type to be.  The strange thing is that my CPU utilization is still always very low.